# Adding input from user to a url

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying something in python using BS to scarpe some data from a website 
I am quite new with beautifulsoup so don't know much about it
heres an example what i want to do

```
https://www.example.com/example/add-input/
```

i want to add input taken from user to add it into the url and scrape data

Comment: You probably want to use Python 3. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html for how to retrieve input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With python 2 you get input like this:

```
x = raw_input()
```

with python 3 it's just

```
x = input()
```

Then you can add the input to the URL like this:

```
url = 'https://www.example.com/example/' + x
```

Then scrape according to your needs. There are plenty of tutorials for bs4 online.